# cy.mockGraphql is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, cypress

Trying to run a test using `cypress-graphql-mock` in Next.js project but getting this error: `cy.mockGraphql is not a function`

Both `cypress` and `cypress-graphql-mock` are installed.

In the description of the library it says: "Adds commands for executing a mocked GraphQL server using only the client", But I have no idea why it is not adding a function.

Comment: Have you added `import "cypress-graphql-mock";` in your `support/command.js` file?

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I forgot to import it into  support/command.js.

Comment: Hey glad you were able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op was able to solve it by adding `import "cypress-graphql-mock";` into the `support/command.js` file.